# Space complexity of merge sort in an immutable array

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

Space complexity of merge sort is O(n) and the method looks like `void sort(int[] arr)`.

If I create a method `int[] sort(int[] arr)`, which does not modify the input array, but returns a new sorted one, then what will be the space complexity of this method/algorithm ?

Comment: `O(2*n) = O(n)`. What your method would do is copy the input and perform the sort on this copy, then return it. Why would you expect anything other than `O(n)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depend on the implementation of the merge sort.

#### recursive

As you can't change the input array in each recursive call the space complexity of the algorithm is `S(n) = 2S(n/2) + n`. Hence, `S(n) = Theta(n log n)`.

#### iterative

If the implementation of the merge sort is not recursive (iterative merge sort), you can copy the input array into a mutable array, and sort that array in-place. Hence the space complexity of this implementation of the merge sort is `Theta(n)`.

Comment: You don't need to do a merge sort recursively.

Comment: Now you have another problem. You talk about sorting inline, but it's difficult/impossible to do a merge sort inplace. I hope I'm just misunderstand what you're saying.

Comment: @MarkRansom it's an in-place implementation of merge sort: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-merge-sort/ (just copy the code of the merge in its calling place). Hence, it is difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: Ah, I see - by copying the input before you start, you can overwrite it with the output. That's not even difficult, but it's not what I was thinking of as in-place.

Comment: In-place merge sort is *possible*, but not very practical. It's going to be slower than a standard merge sort. How much slower depends on the size of the intermediate buffer you use. Asymtotically, it's O(n^2 log(n)). You can do it with constant extra space, but if you could stack frames for recursive calls, you have to include the O(log n) memory cost. And, as Mark Ransom pointed out, if you can't modify the original array then there's the O(n) cost of copying it.

Comment: @JimMischel In-place merge is only O(n (log n)^2), and it is so practical that STL offers it.

Comment: @user58697 You're right: O(n log(n)^2). Don't know what I was thinking when I typed that. Still, that `log(n)^2` term is kind of scary for large data sets (millions or more). Granted, it's way better than an exponential `n` term. But I wonder how it performs compared to a heap sort. Guess I need to do some testing.